# PL/pgSQL function + client-side lo_import

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql, psql

I have problem with importing documents to postgres db. I have plpgsql function, simplier version could look like that:

```
create function add_file(flag integer, sth varchar) returns void as
begin
   if flag = 1 then 
      insert into tab_one values (my_file_oid, sth);
   else
      insert into tab_two values (my_file_oid, sth);
   end if;
end;
```

And psql command:

```
\lo_import('path/to/file');
```

Both code in one file. I cant put lo_import() to insert statement, becouse I need client-site lo_import. There is variable LASTOID, but it is not avaible in add_file function. And it wouldnt be updating on every call add_file().

So, how can I put oid to database with, in our example, 'flag' and 'sth' by insert statement and everything in function with arguments? File is in client computer.

Answer (score 1):

[psql's `\lo_import`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html) returns the OID resulting from the import. You need to hand that in as parameter to the function, which could look like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION add_file(_flag integer, _sth varchar, _oid oid)
  RETURNS void LANGUAGE plpgsql AS
BEGIN
   IF _flag = 1 THEN
      INSERT INTO tab_one(file_oid, sth) VALUES (_oid, _sth);
   ELSE
      INSERT INTO tab_two(file_oid, sth) VALUES (_oid, _sth);
   END IF;
END;
```

As an aside: *always* add a column list to your table with an `INSERT` command (except for ad-hoc calls, maybe).

---

From within a plpgsql function you can make use to the also provided [server side functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/lo-funcs.html). Could look like this:

```
INSERT INTO tab_one(file_oid, sth) VALUES (lo_import('/etc/motd'), _sth);
```

Note that this operates within the file system of the database *server* with the privileges of the owner (usually system user `postgres`). Therefore, use is restricted to superusers.

Comment: I call this function (add_file) from another plpgsql code:  
    `create function main() returns void language plpgsql as  
    begin  
    (...)  
    perform add_file(1, 'a');  
    end;`  
So I cant use \lo_import here.   
Thanks for tip about INSERT!

Comment: @Borgo: I added a variant for server-side execution. That's restricted to superusers though.